# batch script - comparing two arrays

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to compare two arrays and if any array element is same then I am printing. I am not getting the proper output. Only one element is displaying (`rm.war`). See the below batch file and the output.

**Code:**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo "Application list"
set all_apps=(jts.war rm.war ccm.war dm.war relm.war qm.war)
set apps_len=0
for %%b in %all_apps% do (
    set /A apps_len=apps_len+1
    set apps[!apps_len!]=%%b
    echo %%b
)
echo "Installed Applications"
cd /d D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\bin
set cmd=call wsadmin.bat -lang jython -f C:/temp/tt.py -user wsadmin -password wsadmin
set insapps_len=0
for /f %%a in ('%cmd%') do (
  set /A insapps_len=insapps_len+1
  set inslist[!insapps_len!]=%%a
  echo %%a
  )
echo "Compare arrays"
for /l %%i in (1,+1,%apps_len%) do (
 for /l %%j in (%insapps_len%,-1,1) do (
    if !apps[%%i]!==!inslist[%%j]!  echo !inslist[%%j]!
 )  
)
```

**Output:**

```
"Application list"

jts.war
rm.war
ccm.war
dm.war
relm.war
qm.war

"Installed Applications"

WASX7209I:
DefaultApplication
admin.war
ccm.war
clmhelp.war
converter.war
ivtApp
jts.war
qm.war
query
rm.war

"Compare arrays"

 rm.war
```

Comment: Do you want to identify if array B contains any items in Array A?

Answer (score 0):

Test this to see if it functions:

```
@echo off
set all_apps="jts.war" "rm.war" "ccm.war" "dm.war" "relm.war" "qm.war"
set "installed="
cd /d "D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\bin"
set cmd=call wsadmin.bat -lang jython -f C:/temp/tt.py -user wsadmin -password wsadmin
for /f %%a in ('%cmd%') do call set installed="%%a" %%installed%%


echo duplicates:
   for %%a in (%all_apps%) do (
      for %%b in (%installed%) do (
         if "%%~a"=="%%~b" echo %%~a
      )
   )
pause
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i want to compare from two arrays. because one of the array data is stored dynamically.

Comment: Thank you very much. code is working fine. can you please share batch script documentation if you have.

Comment: Please ask questions - which part don't you understand?

Comment: I understand the above code, further i want to do filter the duplicates. i mean, want to remove the ".war" and store it to the array variable.

Comment: Open a new question for another aspect of the the code.  Have a quick read here too: http://stackoverflow.com/tour